# Could you use business rule engine concept in other realm such as security?

Tags: rules-engine

I just learned about [Business Rule Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine) concept. I'm a junior software developper therefore I don't know much about it.

But I was wondering if at all it could be possible to inspire myself from this concept and create an engine for input validation. Depending on the type and purpose of an input, the engine would trigger a rule and actions related to the type of input.

If such an engine exists already, it'd be awesome. Please let me now about it because I have not found it on google.

**My question is** : is my idea at all feasible ? Or does it even make sense ?

Comment: Such engines do exist.  I built one once that used lambda expressions.  Try [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=business+rules+engine+open+source).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I saw drools before. But do you mean I can use it to detect SQL injection payload in and act upon it ?

Comment: Ah, I see.  You didn't mention that before.  The answer to your question is "Does drools allow you to execute arbitrary code in response to a rule (in this case, arbitrary code that you wrote that detects SQL injection)?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok. It mean Drools will be as good as my arbitrary code is. Thank you Robert. Hopefully, I'll find opensource codes used to detect at least Owasp Top 10 attacks

Comment: A relevant concept here is called ["Complex Event Processing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_event_processing)

Comment: @JimmyJames Omg Jimmy. Maybe that's too advanced for my brain. Unless somebody already built an engine based on that

Comment: @JimmyJames lol I'm reading [Mastering Jboss Drools 6](https://www.amazon.fr/Mastering-JBoss-Drools-Mauricio-Salatino/dp/1783288620) and I just saw what you said "complex event processing" in the preface. You're right on target ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.  You can use a rules engine for this.  I would caution you that Rules engines are a considered by many to be a quagmire.  Here's an article that will give you the basic rundown: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/RulesEngine.html

Personally, I think Rules engines are cool but they come with a lot of baggage.  One of the biggest problems is that they have been marketed as a solution for business users to use with little-to-no developer help.  This puts it in the class of products that have ended up largely on the trash heap of failed implementations.  Basically, the pattern is that these tools are put in front of non-developers, they make a big mess of things, and then it either ends there or some unfortunate developers are handed tools that are not built like developer tools e.g. no easy way to do source control or automate deployments.

Having said all that, the special feature promised by a 'real' rules engine (as opposed to a hand-rolled one) is that they use algorithms such as [Rete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm) to avoid an *M* x *N* complexity explosion where *M* is the number of scenarios and *N* is the number of rules.  For this to be a major advantage, *M* and *N* both need to be significantly large.

I personally think there's still some opportunity for this but what I've seen from the implementations (including Drools) is that they are designed to be a platform that you  build applications on top of.  I think they would be a lot more useful if they could be easily embedded within other applications but YMMV depending on the problem you are trying to solve.